# How to implement a form with spanX attributes and with labels to the form fields?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement the following form:

[image: Form output]

Currently I implemented it this way:

```html
<div class="row">
    <label class="span4" for="name">Name</label>
    <label class="span4" for="email">Email Address</label>
</div>  
<div class="controls controls-row">
    <input class="span4" type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="">
    <input class="span4" type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="">
</div>

<label for="message">Message</label>

<div class="controls">
    <textarea class="span8" name="message" rows="18"></textarea>
</div>
```

Which works fine on the desktop, but doesn't work so well in responsive mode, as the span divs stack over each other in order they appear in the markup:

[image: Form in responsive mode]

What would be the best way to implement this form? [The documentation](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms) describes the grid sizing classes for forms that I used above, but the examples are all without labels, so I really don't know which is the best approach to do this properly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've got it. Needed to work with wrapper span4's and nested rows.
This seems to work:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4">
        <div class="row">
            <label class="span4" for="name">Name</label>                    
        </div>
        <div class="controls controls-row">
            <input class="span4" type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span4">
        <div class="row">
            <label class="span4" for="email">Email Address</label>
        </div>
        <div class="controls controls-row">
            <input class="span4" type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<label for="message">Message</label>

<div class="controls">
<textarea class="span8" name="message" rows="18"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you would have to adjust a bit your css but something like:

```
<div class="row">
    <label class="span4" for="name">Name</label>
    <input class="span4" type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="">
</div>  
<div class="controls controls-row">
    <input class="span4" type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="">
    <label class="span4" for="email">Email Address</label>
</div>
```

if your span4 class use `display="block"` and both div's use `float=left` it's should look good on both layouts. Some more tweaks may be needed though.

Point is if you have elements within div's they will break rows together (unless you position then all absolutely).

Comment: I'm sorry, but this makes no sense to me. To begin with, rows are not next to each other in Bootstrap. And it feels like this snippet is not using the grid system as it's intended?

Comment: if both div's float left it will be exactly what you want in both approaches. of course there is some work to be done with those classes i told that in my answer :)

Comment: @AlexanderRechsteiner one thing i forgot to mention and i think that's what's confusing you is, div elements are not rows!! they are merely containers. The way they are rendered is entirely up to your css. The behaviour you describe on your question happens because you have both labels in the same container.